# sql query or php?

Tags: php, mysql

im tryting to look where did do wrong but i cant find the problem, i cant update my database, can someone see my code whats missing? Is always saying me "database error"

Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $types="";
    for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['texames']);$i++)
        $types=$types.$_POST['texames'][$i].',';

    $meta_desc=$_POST['meta_desc'];
    $meta_info=$_POST['meta_info'];

    $id_meta=$_POST['id_meta'];

    if($meta_desc && $meta_info) {
        $sql="update metainfo set meta_desc, meta_info='$meta_desc', '$meta_info' where id_meta=$id_meta";
        mysql_query($sql) or die("DAtabase Error ...");
        header("Location: list.php");
    } else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Fill  Form!");</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: And http://bobby-tables.com/ rides again.

Comment: "set meta_desc, meta_info='$meta_desc', '$meta_info'" doesn't look valid SQL to me... set meta_desc to what? and what's that spurious '$meta_info'?

Comment: mysql_error() will tell you what the error actully is, then you don't have to guess or even ask us

Comment: You're using an obsolete database API and not taking advantage of its error reporting. I recommend switching to a modern API and reading a good tutorial for it.

Comment: Fyi, you can use `implode()` instead of your first loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You are setting two columns simultaneously;*

```
set meta_desc, meta_info='$meta_desc', '$meta_info' where
```

Change your query to:

```
update metainfo set meta_desc = '$meta_desc', meta_info = '$meta_info'
where id_meta = $id_meta
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem with with your query :

```
update metainfo set meta_desc, meta_info='$meta_desc', '$meta_info'
```

should be

```
update metainfo set meta_desc='$meta_desc', meta_info='$meta_info'
```

you cannot set multiple columns simultaneously in the manner you were doing

There are quite a few things you need to consider changing in your code, but firstly try changing

```
mysql_query($sql) or die("DAtabase Error ...");
```

to

```
mysql_query($sql) or die("Database Error - " . mysql_error());
```

this will provide you with a proper error message.

You should also have a read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and consider updating your code to either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) or [PDO](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)

Comment: @Sarfraz agreed - its not the issue - but telling the OP what the fix is probably wont improve their skills / knowledge

Comment: teach a man to fish vs giving him a fish.

Comment: in that case, it should be a comment. sarfraz i right, this simply isn't an answer.

Comment: Updated ...... just didnt want to simply show the fault - wanted to help point in the right direction ....

Comment: @ManseUK: You should give priority to fault first and then best practices.

Comment: don't pander to him @ManseUK, i preferred your original answer

Comment: @Dagon its right though now - i have just moved the code around ... just didnt want to simply "fix" the query

Comment: well obviously i disagree :-) I dislike the spoon feeding on S.O.

Comment: 4 upvotes and 2 down ... for pointing the OP in the right direction rather than simply correcting the query ... oh well !!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$sql="update metainfo set meta_desc='$meta_desc', meta_info='$meta_info' where id_meta=$id_meta";
```

also if you echo out the error in your die statement youll have better debug info

Answer (score 1):

your problem seesm to be invalid sql-syntax:

```
update metainfo set meta_desc, ...
```

you've messed up the field/value-syntax. there's no values for `meta_desc` and `$meta_info` isn't applied to a field, it should be like this:

```
update metainfo set meta_desc = '$meta_desc', meta_info = '$meta_info'
```

where id_meta = $id_meta

Answer (score 1):

you are missing an "=" on your query after "meta_desc":

```
$sql="update metainfo set meta_desc=, meta_info='$meta_desc', '$meta_info' where id_meta=$id_meta";
```

and I'm not sure if it should be like the above or like this:

```
$sql="update metainfo set meta_desc='$meta_desc', meta_info='$meta_info' where id_meta=$id_meta";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively try this:

```
$sql="UPDATE metainfo SET (meta_desc, meta_info) VALUES ('" . $meta_desc . "', '" . $meta_info . "') WHERE id_meta = " . $id_meta;
```